# JavaScript values not being sum in console.log

Tags: javascript

I want to sum user values that I take from spans. This is my JS code:

```
var attackerStr = document.getElementById('attackerStr').innerText;
var attackerDex = document.getElementById('attackerDex').innerText;
var attackerVit = document.getElementById('attackerVit').innerText;
var attackerIntel = document.getElementById('attackerIntel').innerText;

var userStr = document.getElementById('userStr').innerText;
var userDex = document.getElementById('userDex').innerText;
var userVit = document.getElementById('userVit').innerText;
var userIntel = document.getElementById('userIntel').innerText;

console.log((attackerStr - userStr)+(attackerDex - userDex)+(attackerVit - userVit)+attackerIntel - userIntel);
```

That values are being subtracted but not sumed. The number just appears next to another number like this:  `213075`

Comment: That happens, because `+` is a string concatenation operator. Convert strings to numbers before making math.

Comment: `parseInt` before sum

Comment: use this console.log(parseInt((attackerStr - userStr))+parseInt(attackerDex - userDex))+parseInt(attackerVit - userVit))+parseInt((attackerIntel - userIntel));

Comment: replace +attackerIntel with +(+attackerIntel)

Comment: @FahadNisar he allready needs to parse the input-values when getting them.

Comment: @DomeTune Thats right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing this:

```
var attackerDex = parseInt(document.getElementById('attackerDex').innerText);
```

for all the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use parseInt function for all fields like this one

```
var attackerStr = parseInt(document.getElementById('attackerStr').innerText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt`  or `parseFloat` which ever applicable

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here. 
First of all you should know, what type of value will be return from

```
document.getElementById('attackerStr').innerText;
```

If you check, it will be string and you are expected int (number, decimal, e.t.c). 
So first point is to create function to extract value and parse it to the expected type. Something like this:

```
function getInt(id){
var rawData = document.getElementById(id);
return parseInt(rawData,10);
}
```

The scond problem is about using implicit operations. You should go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Type_conversion) 
and read some more information about this.

And to be sure you are ready, try answer what will be result for this to lines and why:

```
var v1 = {}+[];
var v2 = []+[];
```

Hope this helps.